# Use paypal express checkout as a paymethod creating orders in the backend

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, paypal, admin-panel, paypal-express

I need to enable the paypal express checkout on the backend.

I thought it would be easy, just overriding the module-paypal setting the variable canUseInternal to true, for be exact:

I override this file:
`/vendor/magento/module-paypal/Model/Express.php`

changing the line, setting to true:

```
protected $_canUseInternal = true;
```

Now at payment section it displays the PayPal Express Checkout to be elegible, but if I proceed to submit the order it shows that error:

`PayPal gateway has rejected request. Invalid token (#10410: Invalid token).`

I think it's trying to pay the order on Paypal, but of course there is nothing related of paypal neither credentials.

What can I do? I need to change some functionality, that if it's creating an order through admin, it only places the order, but no idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "provision" solution I made, is creating a new paymethod that only works as an internalMethod and naming it "paypal Express Checkout"

Following this example:
https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples/tree/master/sample-module-payment-gateway

The problem is can't have both the same internal code, but for now I can move on with that.

Comment: Hi, what do you mean "can't have both the same internal code"?

Comment: So long ago... but I think I meant that doing this solution you'll have 2 different paymethods "Paypal" and "Paypal internal" with different IDs... The proper way would be using the same paymethod "paypal"